# Scope issue in Access VBA Dictionary?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dictionary, scope

I'm having a strange problem. I'm new to Access and VBA, so it may be a stupid mistake.

```
Private backColorCycle As Integer
Private doneRows As New Dictionary


Private Sub AlternateGroupColor()
    If Not doneRows.Exists(Me.JCH_Shape) Then
        '... some stuff that assigns a value to backColorCycle
    Else
        '... some stuff that assigns a value to backColorCycle
    End If

    doneRows.Item(Me.JCH_Shape) = backColorCycle


    Detail.BackColor = QBColor(doneRows.Item(Me.JCH_Shape))
    GroupHeader0.BackColor = QBColor(doneRows.Item(Me.JCH_Shape))
End Sub
```

AlternateGroupColor() is an event handler that is called repeatedly (by the OnFormat event in Access). Me.JCH_Shape, a string, cycles through a set of values twice: it might be A, B, C, A, B, C as the function is called, so I want to know when a value has been encountered already. I hoped to determine this by storing the value in doneRows and checking to see if the value already exists. However, even though I've checked that Me.JCH_Shape does indeed have different values and doneRows.Item(Me.JCH_Shape) does return the value I expect at the end of the function, doneRows.Count is never greater than 1. It seems as if the changes I make to the dictionary in the sub are reset every time it is called, and I'm not sure why. It feels like a scope problem, but I can't understand why this would happen to a variable that is a member of the class and not just the function.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Dictionary` allows objects to serve as its key. `Me.JCH_Shape` is an object on your report, so when you do

```
doneRows.Item(Me.JCH_Shape) = backColorCycle
```

you are repeatedly re-assigning the value to the `Dictionary` entry whose key is the `Me.JCH_Shape` *object* itself. If you want to store `Dictionary` items based on the current *value* of the `Me.JCH_Shape` object you need to use

```
doneRows.Item(Me.JCH_Shape.Value) = backColorCycle
```